# three.js bind model event on a humn body

Tags: three.js, blender, expo

There are many points on the surface of the human body model. How can I give these points binding click event in three.js ? Can anyone tell me the idea？

Answer (score 1):

There are no click events like in ordinary web applications. You need different approaches like raycasting to enabled some form of interaction. Try to use the following example as a starter template:

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_points